# Azure DevOps (TFS) | REST API | Get user security groups automatically

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

Does anyone has PowerShell script that fetch list of user security groups by user mail or name argument?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample for Azure DevOps:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <PAT Token>")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<organization name>/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json
foreach ($ele in $response.value) {
    if($ele.principalName -eq "<Scope and group name>"){
        Write-Host $ele._links.memberships
        $headers2 = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
        $headers2.Add("Authorization", "Basic <PAT Token>")
        [URI]$uri = $ele._links.memberships.href
        $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
        $response2 | ConvertTo-Json
    }
}
```

Official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

For DevOps server, I think there is no way to use REST API to manage these, because there doesn't have Graph API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0

[image]